# Url .... Rewriting in asp.net..!

Tags: asp.net

I have to do like this : Like in Gooogle and many other site ..

My Current ULR 1 is:
    https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ruanshaomin.game&feature=search_result&rdid=com.ruanshaomin.game&rdot=1

When i click on Login then URL change like this ...
URL 2
**https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=googleplay&passive=1209600&continue=**`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.ruanshaomin.game%26feature%3Dsearch_result%26rdid%3Dcom.ruanshaomin.game%26rdot%3D1&followup=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.ruanshaomin.game%26feature%3Dsearch_result%26rdid%3Dcom.ruanshaomin.game%26rdot%3D1`

and when i login successfully then 
it's direct redirect to above link(ULR 1) ... How can i do this ..?

Answer (score 1):

javascript:

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('continue')!=-1)
document.location = document.location.href.split('continue=')[1];
```

C#

```
if(!IsCallback && Request.QueryString["continue"] != null)
Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["continue"].ToString());
```